# How to automate selenium wait for Youtube like progess bars

Tags: jquery, ajax, selenium, progress-bar

I am using selenium (Java) to automate a web application which uses Youtube like progress bar that shows page loading progress at the top of the webpage. I need to write a wait function that would wait until this progress bar reaches complete and page loads. These progress bars do not have any id of their own. How can I code a wait for the progress bar to finish loading?

Answer (score 1):

The youtube progress bar has the following details while loading --

```
<div id="progress" class="waiting" style="transition-duration: 900ms; width: 60%;"><dt></dt><dd></dd></div>
```

As the loading continues the width attribute value increases to 100%. Then this progress bar is removed from the DOM (well i could not find it in the inspect section). Try throttling the network speed to minimum from the chrome developer tools to see this in the DOM.

You can setup an explicit wait on this progress div width attribute (would require a custom wait) or invisibility or presence. Depends on the language you use automation. Or even a custom wait using javascriptexecutor to run jquery to check for this element.

Answer (score 0):

First here are some methods I use frequently to determine if an element is Visible. Sorry these are in c# not Java but should be pretty close.

```
    public void WaitForElementVisibile(IWebDriver driver, By selector)
    {
        var attempts = 0;
        while (attempts < 2)
        {
            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
                wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(selector));
                break;
            }
            catch (WebDriverException)
            {
                attempts++;
            }
        }
        if (attempts >= 2)
        {
            TakeScreenshot(driver);
            log.Error("Failed to located element " + selector.ToString() + " for " + Capabilities.BrowserName);
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate " + selector.ToString() + " for " + Capabilities.BrowserName);
        }
    }
```

If you replace `VisibilityOFAllElementsLocatedBy()` to `InvisibilityOfElementLocated()` you will change the message to wait until an element is invisible.

If you are interested in the `TakeScreenshot()` method I can provide that also.

But hopefully using something like the above method you can wait for an element that appears after the loading is complete. Maybe there is some text that reads "Loading complete" or something.

I could provide further help if you provide a Url so I can see the page. Hope this helps.